# How to tag multiple commits in git

Tags: git, github

I want to create a single tag for multiple commits(merged branches).

Can we group multiple commits to a single tag , please help me on this.

Comment: No. A given tag can only point to one commit. Are you sure you're familiar enough with the concept of a tag? If not, see http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Comment: Jubobs is correct. You might want to explain in more detail what you want, which should make it easier for someone to explain why a multi-commit tag is neither possible nor necessary.

Comment: For a particular releases we do multiple commits. So how to create a tag for this type of releases ?

Comment: Multiple commits for a single release in a single Git repository? That doesn't seem to make a lot of sense, but the answer is still that a tag is connected to exactly one commit.

Comment: @HareRam *For a particular releases we do multiple commits.*  Why not create one tag pointing to the "most recent" of those commits? That would make more sense than creating multiple tags for a given release.

Comment: @chepner Let's say I have a commit except now the project will no longer compile. I want to warn others of this, so I tag it with 'uncompiable', meaning (this is a commit, but don't expect it to run). I might want multiple commits to be tagged with 'uncompilable'. If we were talking about photo tags, and I have the tag "Rainy", I'd want to tag all of the photos where it was raining with 'Rainy'. I want to use git tags in a similar way to the two examples I've provided. How can that be done. I do **not** want to do `v1.0.4-uncompilable`, `v1.0.6-uncompilable`, etc.

Comment: A tag is a unique name for a single object, not an arbitrary piece of metadata that can be added to multiple objects. (Though this should be posted as a new question, not a comment on an exiting tag question.)

Answer (score 17):

What you are trying to do is not possible. A tag, like a branch, can only point to at most one commit.

Comment: I used git tag -a V2.0 - m "My Message" <commit-id> , it added my head and this passed commit-id in this tag. Can you please explain ?

Answer (score 4):

A really late answer, but you could make tags like

```
v1.2_b7_p0
v1.2_b7_p1
v1.2_b7_p2
v1.2_b7_p3
```

where the last `_pX` part makes them unique, but you can group by the other part.  Possibly:

```
v1.2_b7_code
v1.2_b7_docs
v1.2_b7_demo
v1.2_b7_changelog
```

would work, depending on why you need so many.

But it does seem a release should be a single commit.  Maybe a branch is really what you want.

Answer (score 1):

we can add tag only one commit id 
git add tag -a v1.0 [commit ID]