# Bookmark multiple commits for cherry-picking later in git

Tags: git

This is my use case.

For some commits in my development branch, I want to cherry-pick them to the master branch-- but not now as I am busy. So I need a way to bookmark them so that I will remember to apply the cherry-pick operation later.

How can I do it? If the same tag can be used on multiple commits that would be ideal, [alas that's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30697034/3834). So any other mechanisms that I can use to fulfill my needs?

Comment: Multiple tags? Stick some reminder text in the commit message and `git log --grep`? Cherry-pick them to a TODO branch? There are a lot of possibilities here.

Comment: copy / paste the shas in a text file ?

Comment: as was suggested before, do use a unique commit message e.g : "#cherry-pick-fb-xxx changed balbla", and then later do:
 git log --grep "#cherry-pick-fb-xxx" 
 to get all the commits. For fine tuning of the git log output to get just commit hashes, have a look at git log doc or google. It is important to use unique commit messages for different things, so that in the future you do not accidentally grep old commits.

Comment: you can write a small commit_msg hook, to spare some typing and make it robust,  that would append a branch name to you commit message.If you want to remember the commit for cherry pick - you add tag "#cp" (cherry-pick) to the message:  git commit -m "#cp I changed blablabla" and because of the hook the final message would look like that "feature/bug-xxx #cp I changed blablabla". When you need to get all cherry-pick commits you execute : git log --grep "feature/bug-xxx #cp" it will list you all the commits from your feature branch. if you need the code for the commit_msg hook, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. Create tags or branches, potentially in a hierarchy: `cherry-pick-later/1`, `cherry-pick-later/2`, etc.
2. Create a simple text file and populate it with the commit id (SHA1 hash) that you need to cherry-pick.

You might also want to look into [`git notes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes).

Comment: The low tech "copy hashes in a text file" solution sounds fine. It'll allow for a simple `git cherry-pick $(cat your-file)` later.

Comment: @RomainValeri yes, or `git cherry-pick --stdin <yourfile`